# Sharing AMI to sub accounts using Terraform and aws_ami_ids data source

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am looking to use Terraform to share AMIs between accounts in AWS.
I have the following module;

```
data "aws_ami_ids" "wh_ami_ids" {
  owners = "${var.owner_id}"
  name_regex = "${var.name_regex}"
}

resource "aws_ami_launch_permission" "ami_shared" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_ami_ids.wh_ami_ids.ids)}"
  image_id = "${data.aws_ami_ids.wh_ami_ids.ids[count.index]}"
  account_id = "${var.account_id}"
}
```

The problem is that the data source `aws_ami_ids` returns the `ami_id` list in descending creation date order.

So if you've added a new AMI, it seems to be modifying the already created `aws_ami_launch_permissions` as the new AMI is inserted at the start of the list altering the order.

This could lead to possible race conditions were a sub-account might not have access to the AMI while the resources are updated.

There doesn't seem to be a method of specifying the sort order of the data source so that new AMIs would always be added at the end, which would mean only the new resources would be created.

Any thoughts on how to work around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through them backwards using a calculation within the interpolation:

```
resource "aws_ami_launch_permission" "ami_shared" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_ami_ids.wh_ami_ids.ids)}"
  image_id = "${data.aws_ami_ids.wh_ami_ids.ids[length(data.aws_ami_ids.wh_ami_ids.ids) - count.index - 1]}"
  account_id = "${var.account_id}"
}
```

Comment: Ah, was just thinking about that myself, didn't know if it was valid :)
I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yep, simple calcs like this are generally fine.  I think the above is right, but it might have an off-by-one error in it...!  Worth noting what [the docs say](https://terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html) (see right at the bottom): _"Since Terraform allows hyphens in resource and variable names, it's best to use spaces between math operators to prevent confusion or unexpected behavior."_

Comment: Looks like it working as expected by checking in the state file.